# How to reference a lambda from inside it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get height of a view in onCreate method but I couldn't find any way to remove OnGlobalLayoutListener.

In Java (working):

```
containerLayout.getViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onGlobalLayout() {  
        containerLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    }  
});
```

In Kotlin (not accepting "this"):

```
   containerLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            containerLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "size is "+ containerLayout.height,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Is there any reference or example for this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Referencing a lambda from inside it is not supported.

As a workaround, you might use anonymous object instead of lambda SAM-converted to Java functional interface `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

```
containerLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        // your code here. `this` should work
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there any reason why I'm keep getting this error after update kotlin version: `Error:Exception while analyzing expression at (84,13) in ... : java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method org/jetbrains/kotlin/descriptors/impl/FunctionDescriptorImpl.getTypeParameters must not return null`

Answer (score 6):

What's about extension like this?

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Build
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver

inline fun View.doOnGlobalLayout(crossinline action: (view: View) -> Unit) {
    val vto = viewTreeObserver
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            action(this@doOnGlobalLayout)
            when {
                vto.isAlive -> {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    } else {
                        vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    } else {
                        viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Finally, you can call OnGlobalLayoutListener from View directly

```
val view: View = ...
view.doOnGlobalLayout {
  val width = view?.measuredWidth
  val height = view?.measuredHeight
}
```

Comment: why use vto.isAlive and and later viewTreeObserver - it's the same object cause of val vto = viewTreeObserver?

Comment: @AndreyUglev I have no idea. Follow the doOnPreDraw in Android KTX https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-room-release/core/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/view/View.kt#80

Answer (score 4):

### Simple / clear approach (no generics or anonymous objects):

You could create the listener in advance, then add / use / remove as needed:

```
private var layoutChangedListener: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // create the listener
    layoutChangedListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

        // do something here

        // remove the listener from your view
        myContainerView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutChangedListener)
        layoutChangedListener = null
    }

    // add the listener to your view
    myContainerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutChangedListener)
}
```

use case:
I had to be able to remove the listener, in order to adjust the layout inside the listener itself - not removing the listener **may** result in a deadlock

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100389/writing-a-kotlin-util-function-which-provides-self-reference-in-initializer) and use self-reference:

```
class SelfReference<T>(val initializer: SelfReference<T>.() -> T) {
    val self: T by lazy {
        inner ?: throw IllegalStateException()
    }

    private val inner = initializer()
}

fun <T> selfReference(initializer: SelfReference<T>.() -> T): T {
    return SelfReference(initializer).self
}
```

Then the usage would be

```
containerLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(selfReference { 
    OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        containerLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(self)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instead of `this`, `self` property is used.