# Kotlin: Inner scope - This

Tags: kotlin

I just made use of Kotlins auto refactor and it basically left me with this:

```
coverView.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener {
    coverView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
    true
}
```

Which does not work. IntelliJ shows me that `this` refers to the outer class but not to the OnPreDrawListener. Why is that? The kotlin docs say that this always refer to the inner most scope.

Comment: could you please post the type signature of `addOnPreDrawListener`? That's the only thing that matters here, and I am not sure what lib are you using here

Comment: It's [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnPreDrawListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener)). Why is the signature important? IntelliJ tells me it refers to the outer most class. addOnPreDrawListener has the same signature as removeOnPreDrawListener.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898748/how-to-reference-a-lambda-from-inside-it it's a bug in the converter.

Comment: @cypressious the answer says "it is not supported", not "it's a bug in the converter".

Comment: Acessing the this-instance of a lambda is not supported. Therefore, converting an anonymous class that access `this` to a lambda is a bug in the Java to Kotlin converter.

Comment: @cypressious aha, now I see it, thank you. :)

Comment: I filed an issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10202

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fix your code you can use `object expression` instead of `lambda` here:

```
coverView.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
        coverView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
        return true
    }
})
```

`this` expression in function expression (and the lambda you pass to the `addOnPreDrawListener` method **is** function expression) allows you to access lambda's closure, i.e. variables declared in its outermost scope, not the lambda itself.

Comment: are you  sure a some kind of a labeled lambda wouldn't do?