# Type checking has run into a recursive in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 val cycleRunnable = Runnable {
        handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable,100)
    }
```

I am getting error
Error:(219, 29) Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly

But its exact java version doesn't have any error

```
private final Runnable cycleRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable, POST_DELAY);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I suppose you can do something like an object expression `val runnable = object : Runnable { . . .`  [Edit] What holi-java said.

Answer (score 63):

For anyone seeing this compiler warning, it may be as simple as nesting your code inside a `Unit` aka `{ ... }`

Kotlin allows us to assign functions:

```
fun doSomethingElse() = doSomething()
fun doSomething() { }
```

However, this doesn't work if we're calling the function recursively:

```
fun recursiveFunction(int: Int) =
    when (int) {
        1 -> { }
        else -> recursiveFunction()
    }
```

The fix is simple:

```
fun recursiveFunction(int: Int) {
    when (int) {
        1 -> { }
        else -> recursiveFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. However, I was able to use an expression body in the end by explicitly defining the return type.

Comment: It is second time I found your answer on google and helped me. I hope don't forget again :)

Answer (score 40):

Kotlin prohibits usage of a variable or a property inside its own initializer.

You can use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) to implement `Runnable` in the same way as in Java:

```
val cycleRunnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100)
    }
}
```

Another way to do that is to use some function that will return the `Runnable` and to use `cycleRunnable` inside the lambda passed to it, e.g.:

```
val cycleRunnable: Runnable = run {
    Runnable {
        println(cycleRunnable)
    }
}
```

Or see [a workaround that allows a variable to be used inside its own initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100389/writing-a-kotlin-util-function-which-provides-self-reference-in-initializer) through a self reference:

<sub>This code will not work out of the box: you need to add the utils from the link above or use the [`kotlin-fun`](https://github.com/h0tk3y/kotlin-fun) library:</sub>

```
val cycleRunnable: Runnable = selfReference {
    Runnable {
        handler.postDelayed(self, 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: If Kotlin prohibited usage of a variable inside its own initializer then wouldn't the error say so? The error clearly states something else and also provides a workaround.

Comment: It's just the diagnostic that is not clear enough in this case. There are two errors in the code in question, and the compiler reports the one about recursive types (it can occur in many other cases, too). Once you fix it, it will say that the variable has to be initialized, and that's what I described in my answer.

Answer (score 19):

Show value type explicitly like below:

```
val cycleRunnable:Runnable = Runnable {
    handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable,100)
}
```

This solution solves most of the problems with recursive typechecking problem.

If you are receiving error `Variable  must be initialized` then you have to declare variable first, and then initialize it with runnable like below:

```
lateinit var cycleRunnable:Runnable

//in constructor or somewhere else:
cycleRunnable = Runnable {
        handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable,100)
    }
```

Comment: This solution does not work.  Yes, the original error (Type checking has run into a recursive problem) is no longer shown but a new error (Variable 'cycleRunnable' must be initialized)

Comment: @KennethArgo which kotlin version are you using? It is impossible to get such error because we are initializing this value.

Comment: I was using everything the latest version: 1.3.61

Comment: @KennethArgo Thank you, I see that in latest versions has such kind of problem. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this in Kotlin you need just to set return type of your `fun` or `val` explicitely.

```
fun doSmth() = ...
```

to

```
fun doSmth(): Unit = ...
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this? you can replace it with [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), this is because you can't reference the lambda in lambda body since the `cycleRunnable` hasn't been initialized yet.

```
val cycleRunnable = object:Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100)
    }
}
```

**OR** use the [lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) delegated-properties instead if the `cycleRunnable` is a property, for example:

```
val cycleRunnable: Runnable by lazy {
    Runnable { handler.postDelayed(cycleRunnable, 100) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add Specific type:
Before: val m = MyAdapter{}
After: val m:MyAdapter = MyAdapter {}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).